# Cache entry size and "Possible starvation in striped pool"

Tags: java, ignite

I've found several warnings quoted below and started wondering what is the reason. I've seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Possible%20starvation%20in%20striped%20pool) but wanted to combine all guesses in the new one.

I use only get\put methods of the cache. The class stored in it contains collections and multimaps. Objects can achieve about 16Kb. I cannot use `org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache#withKeepBinary` and `org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache#invoke` becase I need almost all data to process and alter.

I'll definitely change data model and divide it into a bunch of caches. But still, my questions are:

1. Should sorted collection and maps be used to store class in the cache?
2. Is 16Kb a large size?
3. Can there be another reason of the warning then object size and its data structure?

```
[24-11 19:27:58,552] [WARN ] grid-timeout-worker-#23 - org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G : >>> Possible starvation in striped pool.
    Thread name: sys-stripe-7-#8
    Queue: []
    Deadlock: false
    Completed: 3731
Thread [name="sys-stripe-7-#8", id=97, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=3732]
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.read(JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.java:53)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2745)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2761)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3258)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:874)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.<init>(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:43)
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:137)
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:229)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:198)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:424)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.EnumMap.readObject(EnumMap.java:807)
        at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readSerializable(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:604)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.read(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:954)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:346)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:198)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:424)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:228)
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1762)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1965)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:798)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:177)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:67)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1773)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1761)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.completeFuture(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:352)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.onPrimaryResponse(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:301)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateResponse(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3156)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$500(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:135)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$6.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:290)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$6.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:285)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1056)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:581)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:380)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:306)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:101)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:295)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1197)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:127)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1093)
        at app//o.a.i.i.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:505)
        at app//o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

```
[24-11 17:36:16,533] [WARN ] grid-timeout-worker-#23 - org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G : >>> Possible starvation in striped pool.
    Thread name: sys-stripe-0-#1
    Queue: []
    Deadlock: false
    Completed: 4026
Thread [name="sys-stripe-0-#1", id=89, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=4026]
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:946)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:339)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:671)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1903)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1772)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1591)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:139)
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:229)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:198)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:424)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.EnumMap.readObject(EnumMap.java:807)
        at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readSerializable(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:604)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.read(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:954)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObject0(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:346)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:198)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:424)
        at app//o.a.i.i.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:228)
        at app//o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1762)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1965)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1778)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.deserializeOrUnmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2141)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadMap(BinaryUtils.java:2125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1922)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readField(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1985)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:703)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:188)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1765)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1717)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:798)
        at app//o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:177)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:67)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:125)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1773)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1761)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.setResult(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:695)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.onResult(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:552)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.processNearSingleGetResponse(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:368)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$1400(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:135)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$15.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:427)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$15.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:422)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1056)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:581)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:380)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:306)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:101)
        at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:295)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1197)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:127)
        at app//o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1093)
        at app//o.a.i.i.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:505)
        at app//o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

16k is not much, but there's a *lot* of deeply nested deserialization going on in this stack trace. Are you actually sure it's 16k and not 16M, for example?

Comment: Yes, I'm. There are maps and collections of boxed numbers up to 1K in all of them.

Comment: What happens if you store them as JSON, deserialize only when needed?

Comment: I've not tried. Do you think it might help?

BTW, what object size is a large enough to avoid storing it in a cache? 256Kb or 1Mb or even 10M?

Comment: I think you should check that to try isolating your problem. I think 10M is a lot, especially if you have to serialize/deserialize it often.

Comment: I've divided nested maps and collections into several caches and warning disappeared.